# A set $A$ where $A \not=\emptyset$ with no limit points, is not open.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Since the set has no limit points, for any $x$ there exists neighbourhood $\epsilon_1$ such that there is no $a$ where $a\in A$. Now take the point $x \in A$. We want to find a neighbourhood of $x$ such that it is contained in $A$, however this is impossible. If we take the neighbourhood $\epsilon_2<\epsilon_1$ clearly it will not have any elements of $a$ as it is a subset of the nieighbourhood $\epsilon_1$. If $\epsilon_2>\epsilon_1$ then we know that there are points in the interval $(x-\epsilon_1,x+\epsilon_1)$ that do not belong to $A$ hence this nighrbourhood is also not a subset of $A$. I know the proof is obvious just making sure i did not make a goof.

Comment: Sorry, that was the assumption A is not empty.

Comment: The statement is false. Consider $\Bbb N$ with the finest topology.

Comment: @Masacroso Do i really look like I operate on the finest topology? It is the basic topology, i guess...

Comment: the standard topology of $\Bbb N$ is the finest, i.e. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. In this topology all open sets are closed sets too, and there is no limit points at all.

Comment: " It is the basic topology, i guess... "  You *guess*.  The topology does need by specifically stated.  This isnt a picayune nitpick.  In standard metric on the reals your argument is fine.  In a topology where singleton set can be open sets it is not.

Comment: IF someone knows only the color blue, you cannot blame him when he describes things, he does not mention the things color. In his eyes everything is blue, so saying the thing is blue is redundant. I did not know there are other topologies, so please don't be truculent. I think it was safe to assume, since i did not specify what topology i was working in.

Comment: I'm not blaming him.  I'm just saying it is an important distinction to make.  And in defining metric spaces, supposed one learns what a metric is abstractly and that there are others.

Answer (score 2):

An open set is a union of intervals (by definition). Each interval has limit points and it can be shown that the union has at least the limit points from each interval.

Comment: What definition are you using? Are you assuming the standard topology?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yeah I mean this is listed under real analysis so I assumed you meant the real numbers (especially given your use of epsilons and such).

Comment: So an open set needs to have limits points, that is also a nice way to show it. A lot nicer than mine.

Comment: @Sorfosh, no, an open set dont need to have limit points. But the open sets of the standard topology of $\Bbb R$, with the exception of the empty set, yes.

Comment: @Masacroso Are we really going to continue this, lol.